# InflateException thrown by GridView.LayoutChildren when out-of-memory

Tags: java, android, memory-management

I get an app crash due to an `InflateException` from `GridView.LayoutChildren`, when the heap memory is exhausted (the LogCat throws up several warnings to this effect). I am assuming  that there isn't enough memory to inflate the specified XML.

Aside from reducing the memory footprint of the `Activity` (which is a non-trivial task, involving a redesign) , is there some way I can handle the Exception to prevent a crash? (Since the call is not in call chain, I cannot encapsulate it in a try-catch).

Comment: Did you try adding your own [uncaughtExceptionHandler](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html)?

Comment: I did, sometime back, but due to some reason (I was not able to figure out), the app would just freeze and the "Activity Not Responding" alert pops up.

Comment: The uncaughtExceptionHandler has some quirks. If I remember correctly you can't show your own dialogs (that causes your app freezing), only toast messages.

Comment: .. which is exactly why I removed it from my app.